# How to make animated spritekit background?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to make animated space background in my game, i tried using nodes on spritekit "stars nodes" but the game become laggy because of the amount of the stars, is there any program or way to make HD animated background ?

Comment: Are you currently individually animating each of your "stars"? If so, have you considered grouping them together under another SKNode and then animating that single SKNode? That should improve performance.

Comment: yes i have a func make them randomly over the screen , but how i can merge them in one node and animate them, i want the animation of  some of the stars to fade in , and the others to fade out

Comment: You are likely doing something wrong. Creating a atlas with a few star patterns in it should not be that computationally intensive. Make sure you actually hold on to the textures in your scene and then create SKNode objects that use these cached textures. Your other option is to create the animations ahead of time and make a H264 video that is rendered with SKVideoNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one node for the background ya know.

Basically, you create each frame of your animated background as images. You can put these images into an image atlas in the asset catalogue.

Now, you can add a single sprite node that covers the whole scene as the "background". You just set the texture of the sprite node to the first frame of your animation.

Then, in `didMoveToView` or some methods like that,

1. get your image atlas as an `SKTextureAtlas` object
2. get each texture in the atlas using `textureNamed` and put each of them into an `[SKTexture]`
3. Now you have the array, you can do something like this:

-

```
yourBackgroundSprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatForever(
    SKAction.animateWithtextures(theTexturesYouCreatedInStep2, timePerFrame: 30)
))
```

[This link might also help you.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases)

Comment: What dimensions should one use for the background image-- especially if it could be on differing iphone models?